# How to process two different ajax placed in different script tag?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page with 3 dropdowns and 1 submit button, on selecting top dropdown value rest auto-populate with ajax.
And after that submit button is used to submit information, for this, I have written ajax in a different script tag.

The problem here is first ajax is working perfect, but second ajax is not working, I know 2 ajax call is not allowed.

I have tried to do this by writing PHP on the same page, but on reloading the page the previously selected information auto submits.

```
    <form style="margin: 10px 50px 10px 50px;" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">Book Name
                            <select class="form-control" id="sel_book">
                                <option value='0'>---Select---</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach($result as $key=>$rs):
                                {
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php $key; ?>"> <?php echo $rs[1];?> </option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                          <div class="form-group">Member ID
                          <select class="form-control" id="sel_uid">

                          </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-md-12" >
                          <div class="form-group">Member Name
                          <select class="form-control" id ="sel_uname">

                          </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <button class="btn btn-icon btn-3 btn-primary" id="accept">
                            <span class="btn-inner--icon"><i class="ni ni-user-run"></i></span>
                            <span class="btn-inner--text">Accept Return</span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sel_book").change(function(){
                var bid = $(this).val();
                bid = bid+1;
                //alert(bid);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_user.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {id:bid},
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){
                      $("#sel_uid").append("<option value='"+response.name+"'>"+response.name+"</option>");
                      $("#sel_uname").append("<option value='"+response.mname+"'>"+response.mname+"</option>");

                    }
                });
            });
        });
      </script>




    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#accept').click(function(e){
            var book = $("#sel_book :selected").text();
            var memberId = $("#sel_uid :selected").text();
            var memberName = $("#sel_uname :selected").text();
            var message = book+'\n'+memberId+'\n'+memberName;
            alert(message);
            e.preventDefalut();
            $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'accept_return.php',
              async: false,
              data:{bname:book,memid:memberId,memname:memberName},
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(response){
                $("#final").text("Processing completed sucessfully");
              }
            });
          });
        });
        </script>
```

The second script is running properly, but the ajax call to the PHP page is not made.

Comment: `I know 2 ajax call is not allowed` --It is completely valid to have multiple ajax calls.

Comment: two dropdowns are filled and  third is not ?Is this your problem?

Comment: use onchange event of second dropdown to fill third dropdown data.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt it is not showing any error, but no processing is being done on second ajax call. and javascript is a single-threaded language

Comment: @Ricky Dropdowns are working perfectly which is managed by first script tag in the code I have attached. The second script tag is used for submit button, that is not working that is the issue.

Comment: @AtulJain check answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sel_book").change(function(){
                var bid = $(this).val();
                bid = bid+1;
                //alert(bid);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'get_user.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {id:bid},
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){
                      $("#sel_uid").append("<option value='"+response.name+"'>"+response.name+"</option>");
                      $("#sel_uname").append("<option value='"+response.mname+"'>"+response.mname+"</option>");

                    }
                });
            });
        });
        
         $('#accept').click(function(e){
            var book = $("#sel_book :selected").text();
            var memberId = $("#sel_uid :selected").text();
            var memberName = $("#sel_uname :selected").text();
            var message = book+'\n'+memberId+'\n'+memberName;
            alert(message);
            e.preventDefalut();
            $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              url:'accept_return.php',
              async: false,
              data:{bname:book,memid:memberId,memname:memberName},
              dataType:'json',
              success:function(response){
                $("#final").text("Processing completed sucessfully");
              }
            });
          });
      </script>
```

Hi you are facing this problem because of two document ready used .First document ready works fine but second ready is not recognized.Please put your click function out of any document ready.Please try using single script as below.May be this helps

Comment: e.preventDefault(). this also needs to be removed to work.

Comment: hahaha yes but why you used preventDefault,I haven't seen that earlier.@AtulJain

Comment: it is used to make the Updation on the same page only, and preventing page from redirecting to another page.